# Proving the limit superior exists

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> Suppose $(x_n)$ is a bounded sequence. Let $y_n = \sup \{x_n, x_{n + 1}, x_{n+2}, \dots \}$. Prove that $(y_n)$ converges.

The book said that

> **Clearly** $(y_n)$ is **decreasing** and bounded below by a lower bound of $(x_n)$

Can someone explain to me why is it **clearly decreasing**? I had to check case by case.

I found that if $(x_n)$ was decreasing, this was true. If $(x_n)$ was increasing, the $y_n$ stays the same for all $n$. So it isn't decreasing.

Take $x_{n+1} = \sqrt{1 + x_n}$ for example; $y_n = \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}$. I am wondering what happens for sequences that are neither increasing or decreasing (is there even such thing?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $A\subseteq B$, both being bounded non-empty subsets of real numbers. Can you show that $$\sup A\leq \sup B\text{ ? }$$

Now let $A_n=\{x_n,x_{n+1},\ldots\}$ and $A_{n+1}=\{x_{n+1},x_{n+2},\ldots\}$. We then have $A_{n+1}\subseteq A_n$. Use the above.

Comment: Okay that's true and I admit I have overlooked this simple fact. But why is my example wrong?

Comment: @sidht Your example is not wrong, on a first read. The assertoin is that $y_{n+1}\leq y_n$. It can very well be the case $y_{n+1}=y_n$ for some terms, or even that the sequence is constant.

Comment: By the way, to finish off your comment. My proof is like two lines (excluding the base case). Is this right?

Comment: @sidht I cannot tell if I haven't seen the proof.

Comment: I apologize; I simply said $A_{n+2}$ contains just one element fewer than $A_{n+1}$. So I get $\sup A_{n+2} \leq \sup A_{n+1}$

Comment: Yes, that is all.

Comment: I hate to be a bothersome. But I wrote the proof simply because it came to me just like that. Where was my inductive hypothesis? Was my conclusion also my hypothesis?

Comment: @sidht You needn't use induction. Just the observation that for each $n$, $A_{n+1}\subseteq A_n$, which is true by definition, since $A_{n+1}:=A_n\cup \{x_{n+1}\}$. The **recursive** definition is what we use, if you may.

Comment: Oh okay. 15char